# Timer problem, converting milliseconds into date format in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am finishing my Timer project in React. Here is the code of my timer component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Timer extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            count: 0,
            pause: true,
            clock: 0,
            days: 0,
            hours: 0,
            minutes: 0,
            seconds: 0
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.countTimers();
    }

    countTimers = () => {

        let counter = setInterval(() => {
            if (!this.state.pause) { 
                this.setState({
                    count: this.state.count + 1,
                    days: Math.floor(this.state.count / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)),
                    hours: Math.floor((this.state.count % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)),
                    minutes: Math.floor((this.state.count % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)),
                    seconds: Math.floor((this.state.count % (1000 * 60)) / 1000)
                })
                console.log(this.state.seconds);
            }
        }
        , 1000);
    }


    startHandler = () => {
        this.setState({
            pause: false
        })
    }

    pauseHandler = () => {
        this.setState({
            pause: true
        })
    }


    render () {

        return (
            <div>
                <p>{'Time spent on this site'}</p>
                <span className="days">{this.state.days}:</span>
                <span className="hours">{this.state.hours}:</span>
                <span className="minutes">{this.state.minutes}:</span>
                <span className="seconds">{this.state.seconds} </span>
                <button id="start" onClick={this.startHandler}>START</button>
                <span>{this.state.count}</span>
                <button id="pause" onClick={this.pauseHandler}>PAUSE</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Timer;
```

Everything is fine except that I am not receiving days, hours, minutes and seconds value, that I am trying to get from formulas:

```
days: Math.floor(this.state.count / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)),
hours: Math.floor((this.state.count % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)),
minutes: Math.floor((this.state.count % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)),
seconds: Math.floor((this.state.count % (1000 * 60)) / 1000)
```

To be clear, I am not using date object to get any values, only setInterval function to increase the value of seconds, by putting interval of 1000 milliseconds. Has anyone clue how to fix this?

Comment: You are only adding 1 ms to the count every 1000 milliseconds (1 s.). So all the calculations are off by 999ms.

Comment: Thanks, I increased by 1000 and it's working now. Thanks a lot, sometimes, we are without eyes :)

Comment: btw, don't use `setInterval`, use `setTimeout` instead and only call it when you have to. as it is, you start it and leave it going but exit when your state says you should. it will also be more accurate than setInterval when CPU / thread is under stress.

Comment: Actually, is not a real timer, it's a stopwatch, with no determined end in time.